# Multiple terminals bugging out when opening in the editor area on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

Maybe someone knows why when I open multiple terminals in vscode in the editor area they seem to bug out and show only the second one even if I switch between them. This was working fine until recently and it started to annoy me too much not to get it fixed.

note: when opening a terminal in the editor area to the side everything is working as intended and I can edit both terminals.

Comment: I suggest that you post this on [su] and perhaps include some screenshot to illustrate what you mean here,  because I don't understand at all what you mean.